# Getting error while using ggplot with r-shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to develop my first R shiny app. I am trying to do that user can decide what year he wanna see.

The error that I'm running is:

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 1026 or 1, not size 0.
i Input `..1` is `leto == input$leto`.
  184: <Anonymous>
```

My server code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

function(input, output) {
  
  output$graf_dejavnosti <- renderPlot({
    graf_dejavnosti <- ggplot(gospodarskadejavnost %>% 
                                filter(leto == input$leto)) + 
      aes(x=oznaka, y=placa, fill=spol) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge") + guides(fill=guide_legend("Leto")) +
      labs(title = "Plače po dejavnosti in spolu") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      ylab("Plača") + xlab("Dejavnosti") + coord_flip()
    print(graf_dejavnosti)
  })
  output$legenda <- renderTable(gospodarskadejavnost %>%
                                  select(oznaka, dejavnost) %>% unique())
}
```

My UI code is:

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  
  tabPanel("Graf",
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("Leto", label = "Izberi leto", 
                         choices = unique(gospodarskadejavnost$leto))),
           mainPanel(plotOutput("graf_dejavnosti"),
                     tableOutput("legenda")))
  
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you called your UI element "Leto", so your server code should be:

```
filter(leto == input$Leto))
```

assuming that the rest of your code is correct, and that `leto` is the correct name of the column within your data frame.